# Can Google Account auth tokens be shared between services?

Tags: android, oauth, openid, oauth-2.0, accountmanager

I'd like to use users' Google accounts to [*authenticate*](https://developers.google.com/accounts/) (not authorize) them from a web application and to uniquely identify their Android device[s] that run a companion app.  Communications between the platforms will be done via Google Cloud Messaging.

The web service can obtain an auth token when users authenticate their Google accounts via the [Google OAuth 2.0 implementation](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2Login).  The Android app obtains an auth token via the [`AccountManager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AccountManager.html).

Is the token returned by each platform identical such that it can be used as a reliable ID?  If not, am I forced to ask permission to view the user's email address just to accomplish this?

I don't want to access the user's email address for identification--it's an extra permission and responsibility to secure it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All tokens are unique -- that way, you can withdraw authentication for one device/platform while retaining it for another. Utilize the [user_id](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2Login), which is intended exactly to associate the same user across platforms.

Answer (score 1):

The auth token expires every hour so it will never be a good id.

user_id is what you want